# Token balances on liquidity pools

Tags: token, account-data, balance, liquiditypool, price

How can I get to the price in a liquidity pool? I assumed it would be as simple as getting the balances of both tokens and doing quoteBalance / baseBalance, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Below is a sample code I was using to the get the pool information, but the division of the end values returned in the dictionaries base_token_info and quote_token_info does not match at all what I see on Solscan, what am I missing?

```
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
from solana.rpc.api import Client
import json
import base64
from utils import LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4


def get_token_amounts_example():
    endpoint = 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com'
    solana_client = Client(endpoint)
    pool_address = '58oQChx4yWmvKdwLLZzBi4ChoCc2fqCUWBkwMihLYQo2' # SOL-USDC
    pool = Pubkey.from_string(pool_address)
    info = json.loads(solana_client.get_account_info_json_parsed(pool).to_json())
    data = info['result']['value']['data']
    data_64 = base64.b64decode(data[0])
    token_account_data = LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.parse(data_64)

    marketId = Pubkey.from_bytes(token_account_data.marketId)
    base_token_account = Pubkey.from_bytes(token_account_data.baseVault)
    quote_token_account = Pubkey.from_bytes(token_account_data.quoteVault)
    owner = Pubkey.from_bytes(token_account_data.owner)


    print('marketId', marketId)
    print('base_token_account', base_token_account)
    print('quote_token_account', quote_token_account)
    print('owner', owner)

    base_token_info = solana_client.get_token_account_balance(base_token_account).to_json()
    base_token_info = json.loads(base_token_info)
    quote_token_info = solana_client.get_token_account_balance(quote_token_account).to_json()
    quote_token_info = json.loads(quote_token_info)
    owner_token_info = solana_client.get_token_account_balance(owner).to_json()
    owner_token_info = json.loads(owner_token_info)

    print('base_token_info', base_token_info)
    print('quote_token_info', quote_token_info)
    print('owner_token_info', owner_token_info)

get_token_amounts_example()
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: (I get the sol price from raydium)

**basepriceinsol = quotebalance / basebalance**

**basepriceinusd = basepriceinsol * solprice**

**ValueUSDbaseBalance= baseBalance * basepriceinusd**

**ValueUSDquoteBalace = quoteBalace * solprice**

**LIQUIDITY = ValueUSDbaseBalance + ValueUSDquoteBalace**

Comment: don't think you saw what is returned when you fetch the token balances (I tested in Python and Typescript btw). Here is what you get: 

base_token_info = {'uiAmount': 24340.758636285, 'decimals': 9, 'amount': '24340758636285', 'uiAmountString': '24340.758636285'}
quote_token_info = {'uiAmount': 3846894.249247, 'decimals': 6, 'amount': '3846894249247', 'uiAmountString': '3846894.249247'}

Now, if you do 3846894 / 24340, you get 158... Solana price is at 96 right now, so nowhere close

Comment: to be fair, I do agree that your logic is correct, it's just that the numbers don't make sense when you apply that logic to the values returned using the RPC API

Comment: This is what I got:


NAME: Bat ()

---------------------------------------------------
Mint:  FSyViTWXCQPP6haLH7TbVKhAy6waRXXtt2uA47xBQo8o

Pair:  JDwheQTaKX424rEiYwKzGzZqNEepdLRZHTEX4pCarWbR

Quote Token: Wrapped SOL (SOL)

SOL Price: $ 96.23 USD

Token Amount:  1000000000

Sol Amount:  500 SOL

Token Price USD: $ 0.000048116293

Liquidez del Pool: $96232.59 USD

Open Time: 16:08:00

Catch Time: 16:01:06


and the LIQUIDITY is the same as showing in the DEX

Answer (score 0):

The logic above by San Martín Figueroa Pablo is correct, you'll just need to divide the final liquidity number by `lamports_per_sol`, which is `1000000000`